# Multiple Date Countdown Script

Tags: javascript, countdown

I know there are 100's of countdown timer scripts in JavaScript but I have not found one yet that will do what I need so I am hoping the experts here might be able to help.

Basically what I am looking for is a script that will countdown from one holiday until the next like in this example.

```
Thanksgiving is in: 12 Days 11 hours 25 minutes and 9 seconds
Thanksgiving is in: 12 Days 11 hours 25 minutes and 8 seconds
Thanksgiving is in: 12 Days 11 hours 25 minutes and 7 seconds
Thanksgiving is in: 12 Days 11 hours 25 minutes and 6 seconds
Thanksgiving is in: 12 Days 11 hours 25 minutes and 5 seconds
...
...
...
```

Until the timer reaches 0 and then I want the same timer to show this.

```
Christmas is in: 29 Days 23 hours 59 minutes and 59 seconds
Christmas is in: 29 Days 23 hours 59 minutes and 58 seconds
Christmas is in: 29 Days 23 hours 59 minutes and 57 seconds
Christmas is in: 29 Days 23 hours 59 minutes and 56 seconds
Christmas is in: 29 Days 23 hours 59 minutes and 55 seconds
...
...
...
```

And when it reaches 0 it will begin to countdown to NewYears or whatever the next date is that was setup in the script and loop forever. Does anyone know of any scripts that can do this ?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Thanksgiving makes things a bit tricky because it falls on the fourth Thursday every November (not on the same date every year, while Christmas does).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the holiday stuff was just an example so people got the gist of what I was talking about because my first example wasn't very helpful. In reality, the dates I will be choosing will be static. (Every Tues, Wed, Sat at 5pm).

Answer (score 2):

```
var callbacks = [
    {
        interval: 1000,
        callback: function() {
            // do Timer1 stuff
        }
    },
    {
        interval: 2000,
        callback: function() {
            // do Timer2 stuff
        }
    },
    {
        interval: 3000,
        callback: function() {
            // do Timer3 stuff
        }
    }
];

function startTimer () {
    var callback = callbacks[0];
    window.setTimeout(onTimerComplete, callback.interval);
}

function onTimerComplete () {
    var callback = callbacks.shift();
    callbacks.push(callback); // the first shall be the last
    callback.callback(); // call the callback function
    startTimer(); // set the timer for the first callback
}

startTimer();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am not sure how I would use this. Do I add this to another script I found or is this just an example of a script I need to write myself. I am not a programmer by nature and don't really know what I am supposed to do with this. Thanks tho for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest how to modify one of the many already-existing countdown scripts, but just about all of them were horribly written by current JavaScript coding standards (*e.g.* using a string as an argument to setTimeout).

So I have taken the time to write my own **([try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/qm4fq/38/))**. Everyone is free to use or modify it as long as credit is given. Just insert `<p id="countdown"></p>` where you want the countdown text to go, and also add the following JavaScript code, modifying the list of dates as needed (the example uses five).

```
/*
Date Countdown Widget for JavaScript
Copyright (c) 2010 idealmachine.

Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
*/


function startCountdown(dates, elem, format) {
    var now = new Date(), index = 0, targetDate;

    // Returns the next date a specific month/day combination occurs.
    function nextDateOccurs(arr) {
        var monthNotYet = now.getMonth() < arr[0] - 1,
            dayNotYet = now.getMonth() == arr[0] - 1 && now.getDate() < arr[1];

        if(monthNotYet || dayNotYet) {
            // Date will pass within this calendar year
            return new Date(now.getFullYear(), arr[0] - 1, arr[1]);
        } else {
            // Date has already passed within this calendar year
            return new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, arr[0] - 1, arr[1]);
        }
    }

    // Returns the numeric argument followed by the singular
    // or plural name of the item as is correct (and then
    // a space character).
    function formatQuantity(num, singular, plural) {
        return num + " " + (num == 1 ? singular : plural) + " ";
    }

    // Pick the target date that is closest.
    for(var j = 0; j < dates.length; ++j) {
        if(nextDateOccurs(dates[j]) < nextDateOccurs(dates[index])) {
            index = j;
        }
    }

    // Make a Date object for the target date.
    targetDate = nextDateOccurs(dates[index]);


    // Update the countdown every second.
    function updateCountdown() {
        var months = 0, millis, advNow, advNow1, words = "";

        // Update now with the current date and time.
        advNow1 = now = new Date();

        // Has the target date already passed?
        if(now >= targetDate) {
            millis = 0;
        } else {
            // Find the last time that is a whole number of months past now
            // but less than one month before the target date.
            while(advNow1 < targetDate) {
                ++months;
                advNow = advNow1;
                advNow1 = new Date(now);
                advNow1.setMonth(now.getMonth() + months);
            }
            --months;

            // Find the time difference in milliseconds within the month.
            millis = targetDate - advNow;
        }

        // Turn that into months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
        words += formatQuantity(months, "month", "months");
        words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis / 864e5), "day", "days");
        words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis % 864e5 / 36e5), "hour", "hours");
        words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis % 36e5 / 6e4), "minute", "minutes");
        words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis % 6e4 / 1e3), "second", "seconds");

        // Update the element.
        elem.innerHTML = format
            .replace(/%NAME%/g, dates[index][2])
            .replace(/%WORDS%/g, words);

    }

    updateCountdown();
    setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
}

function countdownSettings() {
    startCountdown([
            // Change the dates here to customize the script.
            [1, 1, "New Year's Day"],
            [2, 14, "Valentine's Day"],
            [7, 4, "Fourth of July"],
            [10, 31, "Halloween"],
            [12, 25, "Christmas"]

        ],
        /* Element to update */ document.getElementById("countdown"),
        /* Format of HTML inserted */ "%NAME% is in: %WORDS%"
    );
}

// Run the script only after the page has fully loaded
// to ensure that elements are accessible from the DOM.
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", countdownSettings, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onload", countdownSettings);
}
```

I welcome any suggestions for improvement.

**Edit:** I've improved the script to better separate its settings from most of its code, as well as updating the countdown as soon as the page loads. Also, the target date is now only selected on page load, meaning that the countdown will stop at zero (but when the page is reloaded, it will switch to the next target date).

Comment: You should move some of that config data outside the `setInterval`. In fact, I would say that most of this code should only run once, keeping the part in the `setInterval` as light as possible.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Is it a bit better now in terms of keeping the config settings separate?

Answer (score 1):

I am the original poster and the I have tried out the code that idealmachine has written and I only have one suggestion that would really make this a viable solution for me. If you could add support for hours and minutes to the countdown time then it would be perfect for my needs. Something like this in the array perhaps

`[Month, Day, Hour, Minute, "Tuesdays Meeting"]`

You could use a 24 hour format for the hours so 17 would be 5PM and 5 would of course mean 5AM. This would open the script up to far more people and would make it perfect for my needs.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

This is a starting point, I'm not sure about the specifics you need but this one starts a timer, when it is done (after 5 seconds) starts a second one (which lasts 4 seconds).

```
<div id="countDiv"></div>

<script>
function countDown1 (count) {
  if (count > 0) {
   var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
   d.innerHTML = "counter 1: " + count;
   setTimeout ("countDown1(" + (count-1) + ")", 1000);
   }
  else
   countDown2(4);
}
function countDown2 (count) {
  if (count > 0) {
   var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
   d.innerHTML = "counter 2: " + count;
   setTimeout ("countDown2(" + (count-1) + ")", 1000);
   }

}
countDown1(5);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tested it and it does appear to be a good start, but my knowledge in programming is not very good so I would not know how to make it start over again once it reached the end, or show the weeks, days, seconds left stuff. Thanks tho.